# Does $c^{a} + c^{b} = a^{c} + b^{c}$ when $a \ne b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, exponentiation

Right now I'm working on a [computer algorithm](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1475-3995.2007.00622.x/epdf) that manipulates a [binary tree data structure](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-tree-set-1-introduction/). Within this tree, there are many "gaps"; i.e., nodes that don't produce children nodes, thus resulting in gaps that become increasingly large as the tree grows.

That being said, when attempting to account for these gaps, I describe a cross section of the tree as a collection of sequences of nodes that either do or don't exist, and represent the length of each sequence as a power of $2$. When doing so, I stumbled upon something that I found to be interesting..

Let $a, b$ and $c \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. For a given value of $c$, does there exist an $a$ and $b$ s.t. $c^{a} + c^{b} = a^{c} + b^{c}$ when $a \ne b$?

Can someone please show this to be true/not true? And if this is true for some values of $a, b,$ and $c$, is it possible to generalize this behavior?

Or, if this has already been studied, can someone please provide a link to relevant literature? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you consider 0 to be a natural number?

Comment: Why add some `\:` before each `^`? To get an ugly result?

Comment: @Did An ugly result? I was just trying to have good spacing.. without the extra spacing the powers were bunching the bases, IMO. If this is bad practice, please suggest edit and I will change to the widely accepted format. Thanks.

Comment: The widely accepted format is to suppress every `\:`.

Comment: I've made the edit..thank you.

Comment: I believe I have a complete solution below, and the easy solutions $1^2 + 3^2 = 2^1 + 2^3$, $2^2 + 4^2 = 2^2 + 2^4$, and $4^4 + 4^2 = 4^4 + 2^4$ are the only ones. Which really is remarkable; I would have thought there would be more solutions until I sat down to work it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only triples of positive integers $(a, b, c)$ for which $a \neq b$ and $c^a + c^b = a^c + b^c$, up to interchange of $a$ and $b$, are $(1, 3, 2)$, $(2, 4, 2)$, and $(2, 4, 4)$. Allowing $a = b$ adds the the solutions $(4, 4, 2)$ and $(2, 2, 4)$ as well as the trivial solutions $a = b = c$.

For $c$ fixed, $a^c + b^c$ grows polynomially in $a$ and $b$, whereas $c^a + c^b$ grows exponentially. So there should be few solutions except when $a$ is large compared to $c$ and $b$ is small, or vice versa. To eliminate these possibilities, we need three lemmas providing (rather loose) bounds on expressions of the form $c^a - a^c$.

**Lemma 1:** For $3 \leq k < n$, $$k^n - n^k > k^\theta$$ where $\theta = 1$ for $k = 3$ and $\theta = k$ for $k \geq 4$.

Proof: Rearrange to $(k^{n-\theta} - 1) k^\theta > n^k$, take logarithms to get $\ln (k^{n-\theta} - 1) + \theta \ln k > k \ln n$, and further rearrange to $$\ln (k^{n-\theta} - 1) + (\theta - k) \ln k > k \ln \frac{n}{k}.$$

The LHS is $\ln (k^{n-k} - k^{\theta-k})$, and the RHS is less than $n-k$ (because $\ln x \leq x-1$ with equality only for $x=1$), so it sufficies to prove $$\ln (k^{n-k} - k^{\theta-k}) > n-k$$
or, taking exponentials and rearranging,
$$e^{n-k} ((k/e)^{n-k} - 1) > k^{\theta - k}.$$ Since $k \geq 3 > e$, both terms on the LHS are positive and increasing with $n$, so it suffices to prove the case where $n = k+1$, i.e., $k - e > k^{\theta - k}$. If $k \geq 4$, taking $\theta = k$ gives $k - e > 1$; if $k = 3$, taking $\theta = 1$ gives $3 - e > 1/9$, both manifestly true. **QED**

**Lemma 2:** For $n \geq 5$, we have $2^n - n^2 \geq 9$.

Proof: The bound holds for $n = 5$, and the difference $2^{n+1} - 2^n = 2^n$ between consecutive powers of 2 is greater than the difference $(n+1)^2 - n^2 = 2n+1$ between consecutive squares (and thus $2^n - n^2$ is strictly increasing) for $n \geq 5$. **QED**

**Corollary**: The only pairs of integers $(k, n)$ for which $k^n \leq n^k$ and $2 \leq k < n$ are $(2, 3)$ and $(2, 4)$.

**Lemma 3**: Again with $3 \leq k < n$, we have $k^n - n^k > n$.

Proof: We'll prove that we can pick some constant $c > 1 + n^{1-k}$ to get an inequality of the form $k^n > c n^k$. Since $1 + n^{1-k}$ decreases with increasing $n$, it suffices to show that there's some possible $c > 1 + (1+k)^{1-k}$.

Take logarithms of $k^n > c n^k$ to get $n \ln k > \ln c + k \ln n$ and rearrange to $$(n-k) \ln k > \ln c + k \ln \frac{n}{k}.$$ As $\ln x \leq x-1$, it suffices to prove $$(n-k) \ln k > \ln c + (n-k)$$ or, rearranging, $$(n-k) (\ln k - 1) > \ln c.$$  The LHS of this inequality increases with $n$, so it suffices to prove the case $n = k + 1$, which holds as long as $c < k/e$.

Now we need to find some $c$ to satisfy $1 + (1+k)^{1-k} < c < k/e$; that is, we need to show that $1 + (1+k)^{1-k} < k/e$. For $k = 3$, this inequality becomes $17/16 < 3/e$, which is true. As the LHS $1 + (1+k)^{1-k}$ decreases for increasing $k$ (as the base $1+k$ increases and the negative exponent $1-k$ decreases) and the RHS $k/e$ increases, the inequality also holds for all greater $k$. **QED**

Now we return to the main question. Consider five cases, depending on the value of $c$.

**Case 1 ($c = 1$):** $c^a + c^b = a^c + b^c$ becomes $a + b = 2$, which has no solutions in distinct positive integers.

**Case 2 ($c = 2$):** The equation is $2^a + 2^b = a^2 + b^2$. At least one of $a$ or $b$ has to be in $\{2, 3, 4\}$, as otherwise each term on the LHS exceeds the corresponding term on the RHS. Suppose without loss of generality that $a \in \{2, 3, 4\}$. If $a = 2$ then $b = 4$ and vice versa, as $2^n = n^2$ is solved only for $2$ and $4$. If $a = 3$, then we have $2^b - b^2 = 1$, which is solved only for $b = 1$ (by Lemma 2).

**Case 3 ($c = 3$):** The equation is $3^a + 3^b = a^3 + b^3$. But $3^n \geq n^3$ for every integer $n$, with equality only if $n = 3$ (by testing $n = 1, 2, 3$ and then using Lemma 1 for $n \geq 4$), so this case is impossible.

**Case 4 ($c = 4$):** The equation is $4^a + 4^b = a^4 + b^4$. $4^n = n^4$ only for $n = 2, 4$ (giving $(a, b) = (2, 4)$ as a solution), and $4^n < n^4$ only for $n = 3$, so there are no solutions with $a$ and $b$ both than $4$. A solution with $a = 3$ must have $b$ such that $4^b - b^4 = 3^4 - 4^3 = 17$. But $b = 1, 2, 3, 4$ can be eliminated individually, and for $b > 4$ we have $4^b - b^4 > 4^4 = 64$ by Lemma 1, so this is impossible.

**Case 5 ($c \geq 5$):** Assume without loss of generality that $a < b$. For any positive $n$, $c^n > n^c$ if and only if $n > c$ or $n = 1$, and $c^n = n^c$ only if $n = c$, so either $a=1$ or $a < c < b$.

*Sub-case a ($a = 1$)*. We must have $b$ (necessarily less than $c$) such that $b^c - c^b = c - 1$. This is impossible if $b \geq 3$ by Lemma 3, which holds that $b^c - c^b \geq c$, and $b = 2$ can be eliminated by parity: $2^c - c^2$ is even if and only if $c$ is even, but $c - 1$ is even if and only if $c$ is odd.

*Sub-case b ($2 \leq a < c < b$)*. Rearrange $a^c + b^c = c^a + c^b$ as $a^c - c^a = c^b - b^c$. The LHS is less than $a^c < c^c$, but by Lemma 1, the RHS is strictly greater than $c^c$. **QED**

Comment: Thank you for such a wholesome, accurate and easy to follow response.

Comment: You're welcome! I was actually a bit surprised to realize that this problem can be solved with only elementary methods.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$
2 ^ 3 + 2 ^ 1 = 3 ^ 2 + 1 ^ 2 \\
2 ^ 4 + 2 ^ 2 = 4 ^ 2 + 2 ^ 2 \\
4 ^ 4 + 4 ^ 2 = 4 ^ 4 + 2 ^ 4 \\
$$

Possibly no other solution.

---

You can rewrite the equation as

$$a^c-c^a=-(b^c-c^b).$$

For large $c$, the power terms are quickly neglectible and $a^c=-b^c$ has no solution. These terms aren't neglectible until $a^c\approx c^a$, or

$$\frac{\log a}a\approx\frac{\log c}c,$$ or $$a\approx c.$$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm curious though.. can you provide an explanation as to why you think there may not be any other solution? Does it involve the sparseness of distribution of powers [when dealing with integers] when considering larger values?

Comment: @Charles Exhaustive search up to $50$ yielded no result.

Comment: I think that it is not so much because of sparseness but because the constraints are too strong, recall that for $n \geq 3$ there is no solution of $a^n=b^n+c^n$ and in Wiles´s theorem there are "three degress of freedom" while in your problem there are "two degrees of freedom". @Charles

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: no it is a matter of sparseness. $a+b=n$ has two DOFs, and dense solutions. So does $a^2+b^2=n$.

Comment: That first example almost has no constraints, could it be more trivial than that? @YvesDaoust

Second one has appropriate form. It is a matter of the form of an equation and of small number of degrees of freedom, and you know that, hopefully.

Comment: @AntoinedePaladin: no, both problems have exactly the same number of constraints.